# How to add pagination : super()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add pagination using super().list() method in modelviewset

```
class RecentlyViewedVideosViewSet(ResponseViewMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = RecentlyViewedVideos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecentlyViewedVideosSerializer

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        print('list')
        try:
            if 'learner_id' in self.kwargs:
                learner_id = self.kwargs['learner_id']
            else:
                learner_id = self.request.learner.id
            response_data = super().get_queryset().filter(learner_id=learner_id)
            print(response_data)
            serializer = RecentlyViewedVideosSerializer(response_data, many=True)
            return self.jp_response(s_code='HTTP_200_OK', data=serializer.data)
```

in output, it displays all the documents in the table, but I only need those details in the "details", give me a way to get the exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to do this in the `.get_queryset(…)` method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if 'learner_id' in self.kwargs:
        learner_id = self.kwargs['learner_id']
    else:
        learner_id = self.request.learner.id
    return super().get_queryset().filter(learner_id=learner_id)
```

then the boilerplate code to filter, paginate, etc. the view are still implemented by the `.list(…)` method of the `ListModelMixin`.

Comment: The output is getting currectly, but the paging does not work

Comment: @user15361826: did you enable pagination? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69032095/edit) the question and share the full `APIView`?

Comment: @user15361826: you are overriding the *wrong* method. You should override the `get_queryset` method. The logic to render a HTTP response is boilerplate code that is already implemented by the `ListModelMixin`, which will also do the pagination and extra filtering.

Comment: Thank you for your help and new information.